# Scraping a web page & Formatting it

Tags: web-scraping

I need some pointers on how to go about solving this problem:

I have more than 10K + simple HTML web pages which all have the same format. When I say "same format", I mean that they all will have the same h1 tag at the begining but with a varying text and followed by a table and then followed by a link, etc. So, if you see, the basic HTML skeleton of the 10K+ pages are the same but just that the text will keep varying.

I have a way to iterate through all those 10K pages. I however do not know how I can copy specific text in that page onto a XLS/CSV column-wise. Once I can achieve this I will import this excel sheet into MySQL and do further processing.

I know PHP to a certain extent. So, this is what I can think of:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.SomeWebsite.com/");
```

I then can use some RegEx to manipulate the data I need. I however do not know how to handle redirects.

This is what I can think of but is there anything better? May be an existing tool or better scripting languages?

Answer (score 0):

You may use HTQL to extract the html content.  It has Python and COM interfaces.  see: http://htql.net/

To extract the <h1> tag, simply use "<h1>" as the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with PHP, though I recommend XPath instead of regular expressions. 
Personally I use Python with [lxml](http://lxml.de/) and [this webscraping library](http://code.google.com/p/webscraping/).